# Hibernate count with Restrictions.in with list of Enum objects

Tags: java, hibernate, count, criteria

I am using Hibernate 5.4.18.Final. I have a valid @Entity `Appointment` which has property `status` which is a Enum of my custom type `AppointmentStatus` which is mapped using `@Enumerated( EnumType.STRING )`. Also I have a DAO which has a method `count()` that is counting rows by given `Criteria` like this:

```
    @Override
    public <T> Long countRows( Class<T> clazz, List<FilterElement> filter ) {
        Criteria criteria = buildCriteria( clazz, filter );
        criteria.setProjection( Projections.rowCount() );
        return (long) criteria.uniqueResult();
    }
```

`buildCriteria()` method looks like this:

```
    @Override
    private <T> Criteria buildCriteria( Class<T> clazz, List<FilterElement> filter ) {
        Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria( clazz );

        for ( FilterElement element : filter ) {
            
            //taking care of different types of operations
            //...

            //if IN operation is required
            if ( element.getOperation() == FilterElement.FilterOperations.IN && element.getValue() instanceof List ) {
                criteria.add( Restrictions.in( element.getProperty(), element.getValue() ) );
            }
        }

        return criteria;
    }
```

So the whole purpose of this is that I could select (and in this instance - count) all the records that have any of the `AppointmentStatus` statuses passed in `filter.getValue()` which is a `List<Enum>`.
But instead of expected result I get this exception:
`class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.lang.Enum` which happens when `criteria.uniqueResult()` is called.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Just transformed List to Array.